# Nested stored procedure exception handling

Tags: stored-procedures, error-handling, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one problem.. in every stored procedure i have

```
BEGIN TRY
```

Command and every exception i log into error table.
But now i need execute stored procedure inside another stored procedure and i realized that nested exception is populated into parent stored procedure and after that is logged.

This is my CATCH construction inside every stored procedure

```
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

<CODE>

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        ...
        INSERT INTO ErrorLog (ObjectName...)
        VALUES (OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)...)

        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
END CATCH
```

Example scenario could be

SP1 => Fires SP2 => Fires SP3 => Fires SP4 => Fires SP5

If error happened in SP4 into Error table are inserted rows

```
SP1 : Error message from SP4
SP2 : Error message from SP4
SP3 : Error message from SP4
```

So the problem is that i need 
SP4 : Error message from SP4
and if it is possible i dont need

```
SP1 : Error message from SP4
SP2 : Error message from SP4
SP3 : Error message from SP4
```

rows in the error table.

What am i doing wrong, what is best practise for error handling ?

And sometimes i also get an error that

```
The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Looks good to me the way it is, what exactly is your concern though?  the way it is, at least you have a call stack/trace in the error table, so you know which proc is called from where.  For me, that was super helpful in a data warehouse application with literally hundreds of procs - tracing which proc was called from where and such.

Comment: You are right, at least i see the procedure chain. Okay but what about a situation when SP3 fires SP4 and SP5 but in the ErrorTable i will have SP3 object name with errorMessage but i will not sure if the error message was thrown by SP3 or SP4 or SP5 ?

Comment: Ah, i now see that error from the last procedure is logged too ! I dont know why i missed it before, then this approach is okay and trace is okay too, like you said. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. Only the last nested transaction will record it. 
However I don't think this solution is good if the code calling SP1 creates its own transaction. @@TRANCOUNT will be >1 and the code will have to handle the logs.

```
BEGIN CATCH
    Declare @count int
    Set @count = @@TRANCOUNT

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    ...

    If (@count = 1) 
    Begin
        INSERT INTO ErrorLog (ObjectName...)
        VALUES (OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)...)
    End
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
END CATCH
```

Comment: Thank you, i didnt know that ROLLBACK reset @@TRANCOUNT variable, therefore in parent procedure i can check if the rollback was triggered before. But after thinking i will stay at "trace" approach where one message is thrown by every parent object, which can help me in debugging.

Comment: It Rolls all the nested transaction back up to the parent transaction. Therefore @@trancount become 0 as soon as you execute it. You should always check wether it is >0 before doing a commit or rollback.